# Logger behaving erratically, throwing odd error

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I've been trying to use a simple logger, and I can't determine what is going wrong here:

```
dlogger = logging.getLogger('Logger')
dlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=50000, backupCount=5)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
dlogger.addHandler(handler)

# ...

dlogger.info('%d successes. %d errors.', counter, error)
```

The above code produces this error when it is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 851, in emit
     msg = self.format(record)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 724, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
 ValueError: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 3
```

None of the other questions with this same ValueError seem to explain my case. What is going on?!

Not only this, but after I run the script that has this logging message, it displays this behavior:

```
8 successes. 0 errors.
8 successes. 0 errors.
8 successes. 0 errors.
2015-01-15 16:30:07,539 - INFO - 8 successes. 0 errors.
```

The logger can only be triggered once, but it is, for some reason, producing all of these messages.

Added: even when I simplify the message to a string (with no counts formatted in) it still spams my log with five or six repetitive rows.

Added even later: OK, I think I can explain the multiple logging: I had been reloading the module while debugging, and I think it produced multiple loggers that kept working even though I thought I had overwritten the previous one during the reload.

Comment: Your reloading didn't create multiple loggers (if one with the same name already exists, it will be reused), but multiple handlers would have been registered. If a logger has multiple handlers, messages logged with that logger will be processed by every handler attached to it.

Comment: The only way I can explain this is that you have some extraneous, possibly invisible, non-ASCII characters in between the `%` and the `(` in your format string. The exception mentions index 3 - your `(` should be at index 1 however. Could you please verify this by copy and pasting the format string *from this question* back to your code, completely replacing the line of code you currently have?

Comment: Also: If you have a `# -*- encoding: <encoding>` preamble at the top of your file to declare a source code encoding, please remove it for now - Python then will complain about any non-ASCII characters in your file.

Comment: @LukasGraf In the meantime, I extracted the string from the logger and had the two numbers formatted in, and then I passed this string to the logger, and I don't seem to be getting that error message anymore. Possibly when I cut and pasted it from the cookbook, I picked up some invisible character, like you suggested. Thanks for explaining this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Look Here:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

I'm guessing that one of your variables in this line:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

is empty.  That would make the format string into this:  %() which would give the error you describe.

Try printing out those variables

Comment: These are all built-in [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes), they can't be empty. They are provided by Python's logging system itself.

Comment: Hm, OK that's a good lead. But the code I'm using above is straight out of the [Logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-file-rotation) I thought that asctime, levelname and message were names internal to the logging module, so that levelname and  asctime would always be supplied, and I just had to supply "message."